# Python: Sorting Dictonary By Value’s Value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have been working on a python script, but have come across a problem with sorting my dictionary.

I need to sort it by a value’s value from greatest to least. Here is my dictionary setup:

`{“Value1”:{“OtherValue”:0,”ValueINeed”:50},”Value2”:{“OtherValue”:1,”ValueINeed”:100}}`

the expected result would be:

`{“Value2”:{“OtherValue”:1,”ValueINeed”:100},”Value1”:{“OtherValue”:0,”ValueINeed”:50}}`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Dictionarys and set are unordered entities - by design they are insert order sorted since a few versions. Why ever would you need to sort them? For outputting?

Comment: As dictionaries contain key-value pairs I do not understand the need to "sort" a dictionary, it is by definition unordered. I assume you need to convert this into a list before trying to sort it.

Comment: Wow, I'm really bummed someone closed this one on you, OP.  Here's your answer: `d={'Value1': {'OtherValue': 0, 'ValueINeed': 50},'Value2': {'OtherValue': 1, 'ValueINeed': 100}}
;dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["OtherValue"], reverse=True))`

I was hoping to give you more detail, but trigger happy high-rep users shot your thread dead.  Good luck, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Hopefully this doesn't discourage you from posting again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value Have you tried this, should solve your problem!